# How to convert utf-8 string to big5 with python?

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

I use Python 2.6.6
My locale is ('en_US', 'UTF8')

I try many ways to convert utf-8 string to big5, but it can't work.
If you know how to do that, please give me some advice, thanks a lot.

---

A chinese word called '單車', it mean 'bicycle'

It's unicode is \u55ae\u8eca

```
str_a = u'\u55ae\u8eca'
str_b = '\u55ae\u8eca'
print str_a    # output '單車'
print str_b    # output '\u55ae\u8eca'
```

I know the str_a can be work, but I want to convert str_b to big5, too.

I try out decode, encode, unicode, but it still can't work.

Have any good idea? Thanks.

Comment: "I try out decode, encode, unicode, but it still can't work."  Please post the code you tried and the problems you had.  You don't convert UTF-8 to Big-5.  You decode UTF-8 to Unicode.  Then you encode Unicode into Big-5.  Please post the decode and encode you tried and the problems you had with them.

Comment: Thanks your advice, I will notice this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`str_b` is a sequence of bytes:

```
In [19]: list(str_b)
Out[19]: ['\\', 'u', '5', '5', 'a', 'e', '\\', 'u', '8', 'e', 'c', 'a']
```

The backslash and `u` and so forth all are just separate characters. Compare that to sequence of unicode code points in the unicode object `str_a`:

```
In [24]: list(str_a)
Out[24]: [u'\u55ae', u'\u8eca']
```

To convert the mal-formed string `str_b` to unicode decode with `unicode-escape`:

```
In [20]: str_b.decode('unicode-escape')
Out[20]: u'\u55ae\u8eca'

In [21]: print(str_b.decode('unicode-escape'))
單車
```

Comment: Awesome! It's the answer what I want. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to do this:

```
str_a = u'\u55ae\u8eca'
str_b = str_a.encode('big5')
print str_a
print str_b.decode('big5')
```

Comment: add `repr()` to get the output he wants.